# java SDK for SIP softphone client

Tags: java, voip, sip

I want to build a SIP client in java. A java class that will register with a SIP registrar and will be able to call another sip client.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can try my softphone if you want, it provides a very simple api. It's called peers:

http://peers.sourceforge.net/

Comment: did you configured your sip account correctly? if you have trouble, you can configure the ip address the sip stack will use in peers.xml. If it still doesn't work, please send me network trafic capture using wireshark, log files (peers.log and transport.log) and your peers.xml configuration file. Thanks.

Comment: I tried your example. Yes, it sends some commands somewhere, it writes text to log, but remote phone doesn't ring.

Comment: did you check transport.log and peers.log and stdout/stderr? Can you open a new question with those details?

Comment: it is not connecting to my pbxes.org account

Comment: Do you know which server / stack is used by pbxes.org ? Take a look at transport.log to check what's wrong

Answer (score 2):

Jsip is a good Java SIP client library. It is stable, RFC-conformant and follows JAIN SIP specification.

http://java.net/projects/jsip