# Ready for use SIP client Java applet

Tags: java, applet, sip

Does it exist a **ready for use** SIP client written as Java applet.

All the Java-applet-SIP-clients I've found didn't work even when equipped with examples.

I have an Asterisk PBX, and desktop SIP clients can work with it, but none of Java applets succeeded to connect and to call.

I am seeking for SIP client which doesn't need any intermediate media servers and can connect directly to Asterisk. (I would prefer Flash or Flex app, but they rely on red5 media proxy).

Answer (score 1):

apparently, you already [tried](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3925044/java-sdk-for-sip-softphone-client) [peers](http://peers.sourceforge.net/). Did you check your security settings? Starting from java 1.7.0-21, you have to explicitly enable java applets execution in java config panel. Except if a java plugin is signed by an official certificate from a certification authority like thawte, you won't find any java sip client plugin working out of the box.
Peers latest version is available on github: https://github.com/ymartineau/peers. Java plugin module is peers-js.

Answer (score 0):

[SIPML5](http://sipml5.org/).  Not a Java applet, but capable of being used in a web dev.  It's a fully developed SIP stack written in javascript and enables web development of SIP UACs.

Comment: Thank you. If webrtc2sip is a client-side solution (didn't look thoroughly yet), then SIPML5 is a decision I need. Will be trying today.

Comment: I viewed the demo and did not understand what to enter into the fields if I do not have a public identity, but a local 192.168.1.194 SIP server. I have it's IP-address, login (local phone number) and password.

Comment: So, webrtc2sip is a server-side proxy. HTML5 browsers can't communicate directly with Asterisk.

Comment: Which version of Asterisk are you using?  In some version (like 11) you need to use WebRTC Breaker, which can be set under the expert settings.

Comment: sipml5 requires an intermediate media server called webrtc2sip (http://webrtc2sip.org).